# C# based SQL query throws exception

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I want to use

```
sqlid = new SqlCommand("SELECT Proj_id FROM Proj_details WHERE Proj_name = " +
                       strprojname, con);
con.Open();
id = (int)sqlid.ExecuteScalar();
```

Here I want to retrieve the project ID of a particular project for which I know my project name. Here `strprojname` is a string variable which contains the project name. is it right to use as mentioned above... if used like that I get an exception.

How do I correct this?

Comment: To start with, do share the Exception that you get.

Comment: have you added the connection string?

Comment: Also, read this: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: For goodness sake man! Parameterize your queries.

Comment: To make it "work" you just need to change `" + strprojname,` to `'"strprojname + "'",` but you're in trouble when someone looks for a project called `sick of this job';drop table Proj_details;--`. To fix that you need to encode `strprojname` correctly, but why do so when ado.net has parameter-handling code to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use like below , as Project Name is string ..

```
sqlid = new SqlCommand("select Proj_id from Proj_details where Proj_name='"+strprojname+"'" , con);  
con.Open(); id = (int)sqlid.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Not by me, but I'd guess the down-vote was because of Little Bobby Tables. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code example, which parametrizes the query and uses proper result value conversion

```
sqlid = new SqlCommand("SELECT Proj_id FROM Proj_details WHERE Proj_name = @pname", con);
sqlid.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", strprojname);
con.Open();
id = Convert.ToInt32(sqlid.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 2):

**Problem(s):**

1. You're missing quotes:

   ```
   "SELECT Proj_id FROM Proj_details WHERE Proj_name = " + strprojname
   ```

   might result in a string such as

   ```sql
   SELECT Proj_id FROM Proj_details WHERE Proj_name = ABC
   --                                                 ^^^
   --                                    should be 'ABC' or N'ABC'
   ```

   which is invalid.
2. You don't escape your project name, which might mean that SQL injection attacks become possible.

**Solution:**

I suggest you use a parameterised query:

```
var sqlid = new SqlCommand("SELECT … WHERE Proj_name = @projectName", con)
sqlid.Parameters.Add("@projectName", strprojname);
```

This way, you don't have to worry about quotes, escaping your project name, and similar issues (which you have to take care of yourself if you don't use a parameter).

Answer (score 2):

Flow would be better if looking like this:

```
con.Open();
//string introduced only to shorten lines
string projQuery = "SELECT Proj_id FROM Proj_details WHERE Proj_name = @ProjectName";
using(SqlCommand sqlid = new SqlCommand(projQuery, con))
{
    sqlid.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProjectName", strprojname);
    id = (int)sqlid.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things that stand out:

- You are missing quotes around the project name.  Change to:

  ```
  sqlid = new SqlCommand("select Proj_id from Proj_details where Proj_name='"+strprojname + "'" , con);
  ```
- You should not build your SQL query by just appending strings together.  That opens you up to SQL injection attacks.  Use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).